# Requesting page on button click with Spring, Thymeleaf and js

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

so I've done simple implementatnion on reload-less content loading.
It uses AJAX to load content from another controller.

```js
$(document.body).on('click', 'button#first', function() {
    $('#content').load("/first");
});

$(document.body).on('click', 'button#second',function() {
    $('#content').load("/second");
});
```

For now I have 3 controllers:

- HomeController (localhost/)
- FirstController (localhost/first)
- SecondController (localhost/second)

```
@GetMapping("/first")
public String getFirst() {
    return "includes/first:: content";
}

@GetMapping("/second")
public String getSecond() {
    return "includes/second :: content";
}
```

And that works fine, but of course I can also just enter /first or /second and get unproper content as they're fragments. So my question is there any way to prevent people from just entering /first in their browser or handle loading content server-side instead of ajax?

Comment: No, there is no way to prevent this.  You can make it more annoying, but you can't prevent it otherwise the browser ajax call wouldn't be able to get the content.

Comment: @Metroids Yes, thats true I could make some tokens, but thats not solution. So maybe is there way to load that server-side?

Comment: Those are just [template expressions, they are just natively supported in Thymeleaf if you want to do that Server Side](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#including-template-fragments)...